# Action after window.close()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have some troubles with javascript. I would like to do an action after closing a popup window

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close()
        window.opener.document.getElementById("login").modal('hide');
    </script>
```

> "window.opener.document.getElementById("login")" this part is
>   recognize in the console, but not the modal function : "Uncaught
>   TypeError: window.opener.document.getElementById(...).modal is not a
>   function(…)"

I was thinking it's because jquery is not called before my code, so I added before juste in case :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.opener.document.getElementById("login").modal('hide');
  window.close();
</script>
```

but it's still not working. Can you see where is the problem ?

Comment: Do you have bootstrap included?

Comment: Yes, and the modal function works perfectly in my home page for example.

Comment: If you are using **jQuery** then use $('#login').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {  **Here is some functionaity** })

Comment: what does `window.opener.document.getElementById('login')` return ?

Comment: Check if it will work with `jQuery(...).modal`. your jQuery may be in compatability mode, also check if jQuery is not included twice. Also note that modal is defined in bootstrap.js not in jQuery.js

Comment: `window.opener.document.getElementById('login')` returns 
`<div class="modal fade in" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block;">
</div>`

So what I expected. I talked about  Jquery because even something like this : `$window.opener.document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0].removeClass('in'); ` doesn't work

Comment: you mean `$(window.opener.document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0]).removeClass('in')`

Comment: Can you not add jQuery "again" manually like you mentioned, and then have a breakpoint before calling `modal`and then check in console if jQuery is defined?

Comment: Actually, it was a syntax problem. I did `document.modal` instead of  `$( document ).modal` .. Everything works great now ! Thank you !