# JavaScript code running after window.close()

Tags: javascript

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326929/action-after-window-close), but slightly different.

```
1. window.close();
2. window.opener.location = url;
```

I've tested these two lines of JavaScript and it seems to work, however, I'm curious as to how it works and what are the side-effects of doing something like this.

Comment: The first one closes the current window, the second changes the URL of the parent window that opened the current window. It works because most of the time the second line will run before the window has time to close.

Comment: Here "most of the time" might mean "never" or "always" depending on random factors. If you close yourself, don't expect any more code to run.

Comment: Just make the `.close` call the last thing you do, and avoid any issues.